# navigating between pages in Knockout js using MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have an requirement to build an application using MVC 4 and Knockout. In that I have 4 menus. I have created four different views for each menu.

When I click on menus, the page is redirecting correctly and all the functionality with in each page works.

But, the problem is, when I navigate between menus, the whole page get refreshed. with in each page I have used knockout to perform operation like add, edit and delete without page refresh. I have used the path like '/contacts' to navigate to pages in knockout js.

I dont want to use SPA, as I have large number of records and processing for each page.

Please, let me know how I can achieve the navigation without page refresh.

Comment: Your requirements are conflicting. You say that you don't want to create a Single Page Application (SPA) but you also say that you want to achieve navigation without page refresh (which would make it a SPA).

Answer (score 0):

MVC was not designed to work like you want.

You can use SPA if you use a framework like Durandal or Angular as although it is called single page application, in reality, you can load sections at a time and load only the records you need when that section is requested.

You would then have all your server logic like fetching records etc, behind a web API.

Answer (score 0):

i guess `pjax` will be helpful in your scenario.

i recently created one `MVC4` application first and then i made it to work like a `SPA`.

this is the **[pjax link](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax)** to github

you may need to modify this script according to your requirements.

hope this helps.